# Storing large data (array of hashes) in session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

a situation, there a are few pages of a form with various inputs, after completing 4 pages the data requires a api call and get response.

upto 4 pages i am storing the session values in array of hashes as because user can create multiple order with the same forms .

lastly all array values are being calculated at the same time with api call .

the session store is managed through `gem "activerecord-session_store"`

---

NB: storing through cart will be problem, as user can edit the content of the data anytime, if api call returns error

Will it cause any issue? what should be the best idea?

Thanks

Comment: Generally, storing any non-trivial amount of data in sessions is discouraged. What if a user abandons that wizard and goes to other pages? Will half-filled wizard data still reside in the session?